# How can I format html codes properly with prettier without separating tags?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-5, prettier

I'm kinda new for the web development. I tried coding and the major problem for me is Prettier. It formats codes as parts and it's super uncomfortable for me to understand the code properly.

Here's how it looks after formatting. Some tags have been separated and it's super annoying to see.

Appreciate your valuable solution for this. Thanks!

I tried inspecting setting of the extension, but nothing found specifically for this.

I expect the code to be normal.
[please look for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeGvS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It might look like this because you may have closed your visual studio code's  word wrap feature. Press `ctrl+shift+p` and type `toggle word wrap` and press `enter` to make the code one line and display properly. You can do it by typing a long line and checking it.

Or if you want to change `prettier extension's` setting go to the extension's page and click the wheel button and after that write print width and set the value what you want

[image]

[image]